# How to make ajax calls from HTTP to HTTPS WS using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, http, https

Some of my Web services are in https but my home page is in http how can i make ajax calls to get that secure data. Now i am trying using cURL in the php page. Is there any other option to get using jquery 1.5

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and obvious answer is to make your page https as well. But thats usually not feasible so, you need to use jsonp to circumvent the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You can learn more about [jsonp here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

You could wrapper it with a HTTP proxy call to your local domain and then make the cURL request to the HTTPS from the server.

Answer (score -1):

Some code provided might help. But should be simply a case of providing the full `https://www.yoursite.com` url to your ajax scripts.

Comment: $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://api.somesite.com/Account/Balance",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "username=my&password=pass&output=json&account=8986224232",
    cache: "false",
    success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});

Comment: This is incorrect. A different scheme/protocol is considered a different domain, therefore it is subject to the Same Origin Policy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)